# Calling C++ (member) functions dynamically

Tags: c++, reflection, bind

Suppose I have some reflection metadata, which has the following information:

```
enum class type { t_int, t_double, t_str /* etc... */ };

struct meta_data
{
    void* function;
    void* instance;
    std::vector<type> param_types;
};

std::map<std::string, meta_data> ftable;
```

I would like to call functions in this map, given the function names and the parameters both as *strings*. My problem is not converting the parameters (e.g. with `boost::lexical_cast`), but casting to the right type of function pointer and invoking the function. If I allow possible 8 types and maximum 8 parameters, that's already a lot of branches in my code. What I want to avoid (pseudo code):

```
    switch (md.param_types.size())
    {
    case 0:
         cast function pointer, call it
         break;
    case 1:
         switch (md.param_types[0])
         {
         case t_int:
                    int param = boost::lexical_cast(param_strings[0]);
                  cast function pointer, call with param
         case ...
         }
         break;
    case 2:
         switch (md.param_types[0]) {
         case t_int:
             int param = boost::lexical_cast(param_strings[0]);
             switch (md.param_types[1]) {...} // second param type..
         }
         break;
    case n...
    }
```

That blows up very quickly with the number of parameters and possible types. I'm looking for some solution along the lines of (pseudo code):

```
for (auto& p : paramter_strings)
{
    convert p to a variable of matching type (type id comes from meta_data).
    store value
}

call function with stored values
```

i.e. no branching for the function invocation. How can I do this with the least amount of boilerplate code (with possibly supporting arbitrary number of parameters)? You can think of this as creating bindings to a custom script language.

Comment: note that on most implementations there are certain function pointer types that are bigger than void*. Also note that your stack idea won't work in general since the calling conventions vary widely and also often depend on the type of parameter passed. The only thing that comes to my mind that could help you would be recursive template invocations adding one by one parameter and then finally calling "the real thing". But the whole idea is so insane...

Comment: You have tagged this question as `lua`. Is this the Lua stack or the architecture's stack? Also, if you're calling member functions then `function` should have the type `void (dummy::*function)()` at least and then you can `reinterpret_cast` to the correct function type.

Comment: @Simple, no the lua tag was a mistake, I had a draft question on this PC which I deleted but forgot to re-tag. fixed.

Comment: @PlasmaHH I would be interested in such template solution. I know the stack manipulation is not a good idea, I brought this up as an example. I'll try to clarify.

Answer (score 0):

I came up with one approach.

Suppose you have a vector of unsigned int V and you know that 
every element of the vector is a nonnegative number 
which is less than N (or, say, 20).
Here is what you would call to change the vector V to a
positive integer:

```
n = sequence_to_code(V,N); // or n = encode(V,20U);
```

Here is the code.

```
long sequence_to_long(const std::vector<unsigned int> & L,
                      unsigned long n) {
  long result = 0L;
  std::vector<unsigned int>::const_iterator w=L.begin(),e=L.end();
  if(w!=e) {
    result += (*w)+1;
    unsigned long the_pow = n;
    unsigned int i = 1U;
    ++w;
    while(w!=e) {
      result += (*w+1)*(the_pow);
      ++w;++i;the_pow *= n;
    }
  }
  return result;
}
```

Actually, I probably should have returned "unsigned long".

In addition, you can use this same routine with a program which creates
a text file. This text file would contain C++ code. Suppose you created
"the_defines.hpp". I will illustrate by example...

For example, say we have    t_int=0; t_double = 1, d_str = 2
and there are only three types.
Then "the_define.hpp" could be the file:

```
#define TYPE_EMPTY 0U
#define TYPE_INT   1U
#define TYPE_DOUBLE 2U
#define TYPE_STR    3U
#define TYPE_INT_INT 4U
#define TYPE_DOUBLE_INT 5U
```

then this code could be used in the following
way:

```
std::vector<unsigned int> L;
// add entries to L
long n = sequence_to_long(L,3UL);
switch(n) {
  case TYPE_INT:
    std::cout << "an integer\n";
    break;
  case TYPE_INT_DOUBLE:
    std::cout << "two args; first is an int; second is a double\n:
    break;
}
```

Of course, you could create a text file which has the code for a very 
long enum (if you care to avoid #define). For example,

```
enum class extended_type { 
  type_int,
  type_double,
  type_str,
  type_int_int,
  type double_int,
```

and so on.

You could also write a program which creates (one or more) text files.
These text files would also by C++ code. For example, your created file
could be:

```
swtich(n) {
  case empty:
    FILLIN
    break; 
  case t_int:
    FILLIN
    break;
```

and so on until

```
  case t_str_str:
    FILLIN;
    break;
 }
```

I would also recommend casting using an inline function or a regular
function. For example,

```
inline int inside_int(foo f) {
  const bar & b = * reinterpret_cast<const bar *>(f.pointer());
  return b.d_x;
}
```

I recommend this due to DRY (don't repeat yourself) and being
able to search for all instances of the function.

I know that these program does not handle errors (overflow,
zero pointers, etc.)

Mark